# how to release 'orphan' opencv videowriter

Tags: python, opencv

I wrote a function that generates a video output using opencv and videowriter

I am calling this function from scripts within my spyder/ipython ide. during debugging, the function is still faulty and sometimes it aborts without releasing the videofile. I tried to implement try/exception but there are still instances that aren't caught.

Each time this happens, the output video file remains locked, e.g. I cannot delete it using windows explorer or use the same file name as output for another run of the program, until I close and restart the spyder ide.

Is there a way to find and release all of these 'orphan' videowriter objects without closing the IDE?

here is a dummy example of my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def video_processing(path):
    fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X', 'V', 'I', 'D')
    fps=30
    videoOut = cv2.VideoWriter(path,fourcc,fps,(100 ,100))

    #some processing:
    for i in range(10):
        #result=np.ones((100,100))
        #deliberately cause an error by providing misfit result
        #result=np.ones((101,101))
        #on some systems, dtype needs to be specified as pointed out in one answer
        result=np.ones((101,101),dtype = np.uint8)

    videoOut.write(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is, your code gives an error. You have to specify `result = np.ones((100,100), dtype = np.uint8)` for it to run. Otherwise you get a failed OpenCV assertion.

And I can delete the videos without any problem (I'm using Python IDLE), even without closing the console.

Comment: dtype = np.uint8 is not necessary on my system (opencv 3.0, python 2.7 64bit on win7 64bit). Now when I DO cause an error, for example by generating a result array that is too large for the videoWriter, I get an error message and the output file is locked.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.11  64 bit with OpenCV 3.1.0 on windows 10 64 bit and this code doesn't run without specifying the `dtype`...  @jlarsch

Comment: interesting. that brings up a different question then. But returning to my problem: what happens if you specify dtype but then provide an incorrect result array size. For me, that reproducibly locks the output video file.